# Download a file BEFORE or DURING thank you page load

Tags: javascript, php, download, onload, domcontentloaded

I wanted to create a thank you page that displays when someone starts downloading a file. The script I have works, but it only starts the download AFTER the page has finished loading which could take awhile. I have tried DOMContentLoaded but it doesn't work. Is there any other way I can start the download BEFORE the page finish loading?

**Working Script**

```
** header **
<script type="text/javascript">
    function startDownload() {
      document.getElementById('dl').click();
    }
</script>

** body **
<body onload="startDownload();">
```

**DOMContent which doesn't work**

```
** header **
<script>
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    document.getElementById('dl').click();
 });
</script>
```

**Hidden Link**

```
<a href="file=1234" id="dl" style="display: none;">Download File</a>
```

Comment: Why is your thank-you-page so heavy, that it *could take a while*? Maybe try downloading the file using JS, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax)

Comment: I guess putting a `<script>` just after the `<a>` would be the "fastest" way but you should be concerned by your page load time.

Comment: Do you know what's making your download page so heavy? That's where I would focus my attention, otherwise you're putting more work into patching a symptom rather than fixing the cause.

Comment: Thanxxx guys, the thank you page is pretty much like the home page with the same side bars, footer content, header content as you would have on the homepage. The only difference is the main content is changed to a thank you note.